# Increment variable

Tags: php, variables, auto-increment

I wish I had the opportunity to create dynamic variables of ways, my problem is that I had to make a mistake in my code and autoincrement does not work ...

If anyone has any clues to give me

PHP CODE

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; ++$i) {
   if($vars['entity']->question[$i] == 'yes') {
      $vars['entity']->myvar[$i];
   }
}
```

In other way, i want to transform

```
$vars['entity']->question1
$vars['entity']->question2
...
$vars['entity']->question100
```

to

```
$vars['entity']->question[$i]
```

Comment: What is contained within `$vars['entity']`??

Comment: use a zero-based loop, your array doesn't start at 1, does it?

Comment: Why it was tagged to `elgg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop has no side effects (other than to finish with `$i == 100`). More specifically, the line

```
$vars['entity']->myvar;
```

does nothing. Did you intend to mutate `myvar` in some way?

Comment: @Tomaw I have no idea what you want to do. What was the intention of this line?